# Factory Boy and related objects creation

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, factory, factory-boy

Let's say you have these Django models related this way:

```
class Service:
   restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
   hist_day_period = models.ForeignKey(DayPeriod)

class DayPeriod:
   restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
```

I want to create a `Service` object, using a Factory. It should create all 3 models but use the **same** restaurant.

Using this code:

```
class ServiceFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Service

    restaurant = factory.SubFactory('restaurants.factories.RestaurantFactory')

    hist_day_period = factory.SubFactory(
        'day_periods.factories.DayPeriodFactory', restaurant=restaurant)
```

Factory boy will create 2 different restaurants:

```
s1 = ServiceFactory.create()
s1.restaurant == s1.hist_day_period.restaurant
>>> False
```

Any idea on how to do this? It's unclear to me if I should use `related factors` instead of `SubFactory` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to use factoryboy's [parents](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#parents) and `SelfAttribute`

```
class ServiceFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Service

    restaurant = factory.SubFactory('restaurants.factories.RestaurantFactory')

    hist_day_period = factory.SubFactory(
        'day_periods.factories.DayPeriodFactory',
        restaurant=factory.SelfAttribute('..restaurant')
    )
```

with this test app I get

```
In [1]: from service.tests import ServiceFactory
In [2]: s1 = ServiceFactory.create()
In [3]: s1.restaurant == s1.hist_day_period.restaurant
Out[3]: True

In [4]: s1.restaurant_id
Out[4]: 4

In [5]: s1.hist_day_period.restaurant_id
Out[5]: 4
```

Comment: It's not clear how this solves the OP's problem of creating three Service records but only one Restaurant record.

Comment: OP states " It should create all 3 models, but use the same restaurant.". I read this as `Service`, `Resturant` and `DayPeriod` but only one `Restaurant`, the code sample he provides looks like it backs this up

Comment: Good answer, I think it also makes sense to mention lazyattribute and explain a reason to use or not to use `RelatedFactory` here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed. You deserve this bounty :)

Answer (score 4):

I've gone back and forth on whether it makes sense to create related or FK objects from within a factory, or separately. As you've already found, you don't necessarily **want** to get a new restaurant every time you call `ServiceFactory()`. I think you're better off keeping them simple, at the expense of having to use slightly more verbose calling code.

Comment out the `restaurant = factory.SubFactory` line, then call your factory like:

```
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(foo='bar')
ServiceFactory.create_batch(3, restaurant=restaurant)
```

Or, if you do want to use a factory to create the restaurant but you only want ONE restaurant created:

```
restaurant = RestaurantFactory()
ServiceFactory.create_batch(3, restaurant=restaurant)
```

IOTW, have your factories make as few assumptions as possible, so you have the flexibility to build up whatever data structures you need from tests or different parts of your system.

Comment: Thanks @shacker, your answer helped me to take some height, and I think you're right about the flexibility. However, the dinosaurwaltz answer is exactly the technical way to do what I wanted to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `SubFactory` you can instead use an `Iterator` with a queryset.

For example:

```
class ServiceFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Service

    restaurant = factory.Iterator(models.Restaurant.object.all())

    hist_day_period = factory.SubFactory(
        'day_periods.factories.DayPeriodFactory', restaurant=restaurant)
```

I'm not sure about the best place to create that `Restaurant`, though. In our codebase I override `DiscoverRunner` and create models used for this purpose there (in `setup_databases`, which feels like a hack).